# The FB.getLoginStatus() no response

Tags: facebook

I am doing a demo of facebookapp that only wants to get a acces_token from the app. The app is totally client side and i don't have the possibility of server-side.
At this moment I load correctly the javascript sdk asynchronously and init the facebook with this params:

```
FB.init(
    {
        appId: 'XXXX',   //XXXX is my AppID
        // channelUrl: http://bla,
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });
```

My problem is that the function:

```
 FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) 
    {
        alert('Check login: ' + response);
        console.log("3");
        if (response.status === 'connected') 
        {
            // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
            // app, and response.authResponse supplies
            // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
            // request, and the time the access token 
            // and signed request each expire
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            console.log("Access Token: " + accessToken);
        } 
        else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
        {
            // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
            // but has not authenticated your app
        } 
        else 
        {
            // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        }

    });
```

no response anything.

Anyone knows why??

Comment: Have your tried debugging your code in firefox or chrome ?, is your function getting called ?